# Signup to more lists in MailChimp signup-form

Tags: forms, email, mailchimp

I have a question regarding the signup-forms in MailChimp.

Is it possible to create the signup form including some checkboxes, so the users can descide which lists they want to sign up for?

Let's say that I have four lists, and I create a signup form for one of the lists. Then the form should include a name-field, e-mail-field and three checkboxes.
So when a user signs up, they are going on my primary lists, and they have the option of going on the three other lists as well, by checking the checkboxes in the form.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

As each list is a different group of subscribers, they all have to subscribe and unsubscribe independently from one another. A better way to do it is to run one BIG list instead.

By having one big list of everyone, you can have custom fields designating each sub-list. They can then edit their preferences/subscribe/unsubscribe for all lists in one form.